# Find the minimum of a energy conservation equation.

Tags: maxima-minima, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I have an equation for two particle collisions (the equation is just energy-momentum conservation):

$$k_{A,x}+k_{B,x} = p_{1,x}+p_{2,x}$$
$$k_{A,y}+k_{B,y} = p_{1,y}+p_{2,y}$$
$$k_{A,z}+k_{B,z} = p_{1,z}+p_{2,z}$$
$$\sqrt{m_{1}^{2}+\mathbf{k}_{A}^{2}}+\sqrt{m_{2}^{2}+\mathbf{k}_{B}^{2}} = \sqrt{m_{1}^{2}+\mathbf{p}_{1}^{2}}+\sqrt{m_{2}^{2}+\mathbf{p}_{2}^{2}}.$$

where, $k_{A,x}\in[p_{c,x}-3\sigma,p_{c,x}+3\sigma]$, $k_{B,x}=-k_{A,x}$ and $k_{A,y},k_{B,y},k_{A,z},k_{B,z}\in[-3\sigma,3\sigma]$, $p_{c,x}$ and $\sigma$ is a positive number, and $ p_{c,x} > 3\sigma $.

The first three equations will give $\mathbf{p}_{2}$ in terms of $\mathbf{k}_{A},\mathbf{k}_{B},\mathbf{p}_{1}$.

I would like to know the minimum and maximum value of $|\mathbf{p}_{1}|$ if we already know $|\mathbf{k}_{A}|_{min},|\mathbf{k}_{A}|_{max},|\mathbf{k}_{B}|_{min},|\mathbf{k}_{B}|_{max}$. Or the boundary for $|\mathbf{p}_{1}|$ in terms of $p_{c,x}$ and $\sigma$,i.e., I would like to know the minimum and maximum value of $|\mathbf{p}_{1}|$ in terms of $p_{c,x}$ and $\sigma$.

Here is a solution I found for this question, which I can not persuade myself, but it may help clear the question.

Since $\mathbf{k}_{A}$ and $\mathbf{k}_{B}$ denoting the input momentum of two incoming particles, if $|\mathbf{k}_{A}|$ and $|\mathbf{k}_{B}|$ all take the minimum values, i.e., $\mathbf{k}_{A}=(p_{c,x}-3\sigma,0,0)$ and $\mathbf{k}_{B}=(-p_{c,x}+3\sigma,0,0)$ hence $\mathbf{k}_{A}+\mathbf{k}_{B}=\mathbf{p}_{1}+\mathbf{p}_{2}$, the outcoming particles would have the minimum values. Thus we have 
 $$\sqrt{m_{1}^{2}+\mathbf{k}_{A}^{2}}+\sqrt{m_{2}^{2}+\mathbf{k}_{A}^{2}} = \sqrt{m_{1}^{2}+\mathbf{p}_{1}^{2}}+\sqrt{m_{2}^{2}+\mathbf{p}_{1}^{2}}.$$
Thus one can easily see that the minimum value for $|\mathbf{p}_{1}|$ is $|\mathbf{k}_{A}|_{min}$

This is somewhat reluctant.

Does anyone have once encountered such problem or how to make my proof more convinsing?

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

Or equivalently, if $\delta_{1},\delta_{2},\delta_{3},\delta_{4}\in[-3\sigma,3\sigma]$ and $p_{c,x}$ and $\sigma$ are positive numbers,  and $ p_{c,x} > 3\sigma $., how to prove the following inequality to be wrong:
$$\sqrt{m_{1}^{2}+(-p_{c,x}+\delta_{1})^{2}+\delta_{2}^{2}}+\sqrt{m_{2}^{2}+(p_{c,x}+\delta_{3})^{2}+\delta_{4}^{2}} < \sqrt{m_{1}^{2}+(p_{c,x}-3\sigma)^{2}}+\sqrt{m_{2}^{2}+(p_{c,x}-3\sigma)^{2}+(\delta_{1}+\delta_{3})^{2}+(\delta_{2}+\delta_{4})^{2}}$$

Comment: It would help to know the following: (1) the meaning of the equations you give (just cite a link or name or something), and (2) the function you are trying to minimize or maximize. . . also the meaning of the variables would help a little as well.

Comment: @se2018, I have updated the question.